# Pseudo elements disappear on mobile

Tags: pseudo-element

I’m using the pseudo elements ::before and ::after to underline text on my about page: http://www.alexanderschlosser.de/wordpress/about.

For some weird reason everything works great on desktop, but no matter what mobile browser I use on my iPhone it won’t show the underlines. Or they actually show up for a split second, but disappear afterwards.

It’s even weirder as I use the exact same CSS styling for the main navigation and it works perfectly fine for those links on all devices.

Any idea what the problem might be?

_

Here’s the CSS

```
.linkBio::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: -1 !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #252526;
}

/*CREATE COLORED BACKGROUND AND HIDE IT*/
.linkBio::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: -2 !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #DFFAD6;
  visibility: hidden;
  /*opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.05s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.05s ease-in-out 0s;*/
}

/*SHOW COLORED BACKGROUND ON HOVER*/
.linkBio:hover::after {
  visibility: visible;
  /*opacity: 1;*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the z-index you've set for them. Change them to `0` and it will work as expected.

Comment: Hey, just had a thought—instead of using both `::before` and `::after` , why not use just `::after` with `border-bottom: 1px solid #000;` applied? remove the `visibility` property and have the background color change to the green on `:hover`? That should solve any layer hierarchy issues you're having.